# How to study $e^{-t}\sin(t)$ over $\mathbb R$?

Tags: limits, derivatives, trigonometry

I studied the variations of the  $e^{-t} \sin(t)$ over the interval $(0 ,\pi)$ and I want to extend this analysis to $\mathbb R$. This function is not periodic, however, but it behaves similarly every $2\pi$ (except the scale caused by the $e^{-t}$).

In fact, studying the variations of this function consists of analyzing the sign of its derivative $ \sqrt{2} e^{-t}\cos(t+\frac{\pi}{4})$ but I don't see how I can extend this analysis to $\mathbb R$.

Comment: It is possible to give an explicit formula for the variation over $[0,x]$ say. From this explicit formula it follows that $$
\int_0^x {\sqrt 2 e^{ - t} \left| {\cos \left( {t + \frac{\pi }{4}} \right)} \right|dt}  = \sqrt 2 \frac{{e^{3\pi /4} }}{{e^\pi   - 1}} + \mathcal{O}(e^{ - x} )=0.6739164544\ldots+ \mathcal{O}(e^{ - x} ).
$$

Comment: Thanks for your help. But I still have some trouble, how can I draw the table of signs of this function ? can I parameterise the table ?

Comment: It is positive when $$
\left( {2k - \tfrac{3}{4}} \right)\pi  < t < \left( {2k + \tfrac{1}{4}} \right)\pi 
$$ and negative when $$
\left( {2k + \tfrac{1}{4}} \right)\pi  < t < \left( {2k + \tfrac{5}{4}} \right)\pi 
.$$ Here $k\in \mathbb Z$.

Comment: I dont see how can I localise the interval $(0,2\pi)$, my idea is to parameterize the table of signs of this interval with $k$.

Comment: If $f(t)= e^{-t} \sin(t)$ then $f(t+n2\pi)=\left(e^{-2\pi}\right)^n f(t)$ and $f'(t+n2\pi)=\left(e^{-2\pi}\right)^n f'(t)$ for all integers $n$ and since you know what happens when $t \in [0,2\pi]$ $\big($for example $f'(t)=e^{-t} (\cos(t)-\sin(t))\big)$ this tells you what happens for all $t \in \mathbb R$.  Note that $e^{-2\pi} \approx 0.001867443$ so damping is rapid; this might also be $i^{4i}$.

Comment: Thanks for your replay. You can respond so that I can validate the answer.